# openssl: create certificate with nickname

Tags: openssl, certificate

I created private, public keys with:

> openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes 
>           -days 36500 
>           -keyout MOK.key.priv.pem 
>           -out MOK.key.publ.pem 
>           -outform PEM

Then I created a certificate with the command:

> openssl req -new -x509 -key MOK.key.priv.pem -out MOK.cert.pem -outform PEM

How can I set the nickname of the certificate ?

Reason:
I'm trying to use pesign with the command:

> pesign -n ./db -i bzImage -o bzImage.signed -c zvivered -s

and got:

cms_common.c:find_certificate:462: could not find certificate in list: security library: bad database.
pesign: Could not find certificate zvivered

Can you please help ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

I failed to use pesign. 
Instead I used this link: [sbsign](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot)
It works.

Good luck.